# Use FormType for "new" and "edit" data in Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, frameworks

I'm trying to use one form to add and edit data in my "Customer" Entity.

Here is the FormType:

```
    <?php

namespace Ourentec\CustomersBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class CustomerType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Nombre *',
                'required' => true,
                'max_length' => 20,
            ))
            ->add('lastname', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Apellido',
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('address', 'textarea', array(
                'label' => 'Dirección',
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('phone', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Teléfono *',
                'required' => true
            ))
            ->add('pass', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Contraseña *',
                'required' => true
            ))
            ->add('tasks', 'textarea', array(
                'label' => 'Tareas',
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('email', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Email',
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('status', 'choice', array(
                'label' => 'Estado',
                'required' => true,
                'choices' => array(
                    '' => 'Selecciona un estado',
                    'Pendiente' => 'Pendiente',
                    'En Curso' => 'En Curso',
                    'Terminado' => 'Terminado'
                )
            ))
            ->add('location', 'choice', array(
                'label' => 'Ubicación',
                'required' => true,
                'choices' => array(
                    '' => 'Selecciona una ubicación',
                    'Taller' => 'Taller',
                    'Tienda' => 'Tienda',
                    'Servicio Técnico Oficial' => 'Servicio Técnico Oficial',
                    'Entregado' => 'Entregado'
                )
            ))
            ->add('save', 'submit', array(
                'label' => 'Añadir'
            ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'ourentec_customersbundle_customer';
    }
}
```

And here are the controllers for new and edit "customer":

```
public function newCustomerAction(Request $request)
    {
        $customer = new Customer();

        // invoke form and associate a customer object
        $form = $this->createForm(new CustomerType(), $customer);

        // check if form is submitted
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($customer);
            $em->flush();

            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
                'msg',
                'Ficha creada correctamente!'
            );
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('customers_index'));

        }

        return $this->render('CustomersBundle:Customers:new.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }

    public function editCustomerAction(Request $request)
    {
        $customerModel = $this->get('customer_model');
        $historyModel = $this->get('history_model');

        $customer = $customerModel->getCustomerForAdmin($request->get('id'));

        $histories = $historyModel->getHistory($request->get('id'));

        $form = $this->createForm(new CustomerType(), $customer);


        return $this->render('CustomersBundle:Customers:edit.html.twig', array(
            'customer' => $customer,
            'histories' => $histories,
            'form' => $form->createView()));
    }
```

And to end, the edit view, because the "new" one works perfectly:

```
{% block content %}
    {% if customer is defined %}
        {% set customer = customer[0] %}
        <h2>Datos de {{ customer.name }}</h2>
        <a href="{{ path('customers_index') }}" class="btn">Volver</a>
        <p></p>

        {{ form_start(form) }}
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>{{ customer.id }}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Fecha de Alta</td>
                <td>{{ customer.date|date("d-m-Y @ H:m:s") }}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Nombre</td>
                <td>{{ form_widget(form.name) }}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Estado Actual</td>
                <td>{{ customer.status }}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Ubicación Actual</td>
                <td>{{ customer.location }}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Apellido</td>
                <td>{{ form_widget(form.lastname) }}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Dirección</td>
                <td>{{ form_widget(form.address) }}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Teléfono</td>
                <td>{{ form_widget(form.phone) }}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Contraseña</td>
                <td>{{ form_widget(form.pass) }}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Tareas</td>
                <td>
                    {{ form_widget(form.tasks) }}
                    <input type="button" class="btn" id="btn_tasks" value="Archivar"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>{{ form_widget(form.email) }}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Estado *</td>
                <td>
                    {{ form_widget(form.status) }}
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Ubicación *</td>
                <td>
                    {{ form_widget(form.location) }}
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="edit" value="Guardar"/>
                    <a href="{{ path('customers_index') }}" class="btn">Volver</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        {{ form_end(form) }}

        {% if histories is defined %}
            {% set histories = histories[0] %}
            <h3>Historial de Tareas</h3>
            <table class="table">
                {% for history in histories %}
                    {% if history.tasks is defined %}
                        <tr>
                            <td class="history_text">{{ history.date|date("d-m-Y @ H:m:s") }}</td>
                            <td>{{ history.tasks }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="" class="btn btn-danger"
                                   onclick="return confirm('¿Estás seguro de que deseas borrar esta entrada?')">Borrar</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Well, my problem is that I can't pre-fill the Entity data into text fields. As you can see, in my controller (editCustomerAction) I'm getting the customer info from my database (I checked it in my error_log and in the Symfony2 toolbar), and I pass that info to the view.
But I don't know why it doesn't work. I read de official docs but there are no examples to pre-fill data...

Thanks in advance!

EDITED: Here is the model. I do a "getArrayResult()" in the DQL because if a do a

```
$customer = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CustomersBundle:Customer')->find($request->get('id'));
```

I get a "PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size..." error..

Model functions:

```
class CustomerModel
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }


    public function getAllCustomersForAdmin($userId)
    {
        $customers = $this->em->createQuery(
            'select c, ctrl.seen, ctrl.date as edited from CustomersBundle:Customer c
            join CustomersBundle:Control ctrl
            where c.id = ctrl.customer and ctrl.user = :id order by ctrl.date desc, c.date desc')
            ->setParameter('id', $userId)
            ->getArrayResult();

        return $customers;
    }

    public function getCustomerForAdmin($customerId)
    {
        $customer = $this->em->createQuery(
            'select c from CustomersBundle:Customer c where c.id = :id')->setParameter('id', $customerId)
            ->getArrayResult();

        return $customer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does your template use customer[0] when customer is not an array?

Comment: Because I get the info with a "getArrayResult()" in the model... The problem is if I do a "$this->getDoctrine->getRepository('CustomersBundle:Customer')->find($id)"
I get a "PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size..." Error.

Comment: And yet you are passing the $customer (which I guess is an array) to the form type which expects a single entity. You have a mismatch someplace.  The $repo->find($id) should work and return a single customer.  As should your getCustomerForAdmin.  I suspect that you may have written some code which lists multiple customers somewhere and then you copied/pasted it to deal with a single customer?

Comment: Well, the error I had with "PHP Fatal Error" was caused by "error_log(print_r(//here the result of query, true));
But my result now (using "find($id)" is an array with a [0] subarray and inside this, all the customer info...)

I was looking at Symfony Toolbar and I saw that some relations are not correct..
"The mappings Ourentec\CustomersBundle\Entity\Control#user and Ourentec\UsersBundle\Entity\User#controls are inconsistent with each other."

But to do a query on a single entity I supose it is not a problem.

Comment: Done! I checked my entities relations and executed a "doctrine:schema:update --force" and now it's fine! My "edit" form pre-fills with Entity data!!

Thanks a lot for your help @Cerad :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're are giving an array to your form. That's why that didn't work.

In your model, you've to return a single result :

```
public function getCustomerForAdmin($customerId)
{
    $customer = $this->em->createQuery(
        'select c from CustomersBundle:Customer c where c.id = :id')->setParameter('id', $customerId)
        ->getSingleResult();

    return $customer;
}
```

You can use the function : `getOneOrNullResult()` to return a null if the customer doesn't exist. In this case, the `getSingleResult()` will throw an error.

Comment: So is a good practice to do a `getOneOrNullResult()` and then in de controller check if $customer is null and show a "flashMessage" for example? Thanks :)

Comment: Depending of the degree of trust you've on your base data ^^ But yes, it's a good pratice to systematically check if the data returned is good. That could be save you lots of time on "unexplained side effects".

Comment: Haha!! Ok. Thanks again :))